# pod dns is not resolved in k8s

Tags: dns, kubernetes, load-balancing, kubernetes-pod

I have 2 services named A and  B

I have pods a1,a2,a3 for Service A.

I have pods b1,b2,b3 for Service B.

Service A -> Type = ClusterIP

Service B -> Type= LoadBalancer

if I try to do nslookup from a1 -> b1 I am getting below error.

```
  >kubectl exec a1 -- nslookup b1

  nslookup: can't resolve '(null)': Name does not resolve
  nslookup: can't resolve 'cassandra-0': Name does not resolve
  command terminated with exit code 1
```

please help me to find the issue and why it's not reachable from other pods

updated with actual info::

```
                                    root-user> kubectl get  services --all-namespaces -o wide
        NAMESPACE     NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP                                                               PORT(S)                      AGE       SELECTOR
        default       kubernetes             ClusterIP      100.24.1.0       <none>                                                                    443/TCP                      26d       <none>
        default       registration-service   ClusterIP      None             <none>                                                                    8080/TCP                     18d       app=registration-service
        default       app-framework          ClusterIP      None             <none>                                                                    24366/TCP                    25d       app=app-framework
        default       stt                    LoadBalancer   100.56.9.26      a548cdb75447611e897960efe53682ba-1445165219.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com   8443:31327/TCP               3d        app=stt
        kube-system   kube-dns               ClusterIP      100.46.0.10      <none>                                                                    53/UDP,53/TCP                26d       k8s-app=kube-dns
        kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard   ClusterIP      100.96.205.42    <none>                                                                    443/TCP                      26d       k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
```

Comment: Are service A and B in the same namespace?

Comment: Also, since you're apparently trying to look up the pod DNS (where you should really be connecting to the VIP the service provides) did you take into account the correct syntax? See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pods for details. BTW, a concrete example rather than the abstract one you provided here makes it way easier to help you.

Comment: yes both services are in same namespace 'default'.

Answer (score 1):

It works as described in the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pods). Here a simple example:

```
# in one terminal: 
$ kubectl run -i -t --rm there --restart=Never --image=quay.io/mhausenblas/jump:0.2 -- sh

# in another terminal
$ kubectl describe pod there | grep IP
IP:           172.17.0.7
$ kubectl run -i -t --rm here --restart=Never --image=quay.io/mhausenblas/jump:0.2 -- sh
~ $ nslookup 172-17-0-7.default.pod
nslookup: can't resolve '(null)': Name does not resolve

Name:      172-17-0-7.default.pod
Address 1: 172.17.0.7
```

Comment: can't we access pod from stt in pod from app-framework ?

Comment: Yes you can but that's not what you asked. In your example you asked how to lookup the DNS of the pod (b1) not the service. Please make clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I mean I want to access b1 from a1 where a1, b1 are pod names like stt-6b65f8c98c-lqn67(in example i used simple names for understanding).

Comment: And I explained you above how to access the pods. The DNS entry is not via the pods names but via the pods IPs as it is described in the docs and as I've shown above. I really don't know what else I can say?